# Baked eggplant is bitter - is there a way to fix it?

Tags: vegetables, eggplant

Do I have to throw away bitter eggplant *after* I have baked it?  Can something be done or do I have to throw it away?

Comment: IME, peel it beforehand is the only way that works.

Answer (score 2):

Some extra salt will help hide the bitterness, but obviously that only goes so far before it's too salty.

Answer (score 2):

I was roasting cubed eggplant and cherry tomatoes in the oven.  Took one out to taste it and it was very BITTER!  I did  not have time to salt them first before cooking.  I removed them from the roasting tray and put the eggplant into a hot frying pan with olive oil and constantly stirring it to encourage all the moisture to leach out.  Then I added 1/4 teaspoon of granulated sugar and 2 Tablespoons of milk and 1/4 cup parmesan cheese.  It removed and disguised all the bitterness.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

As already baked, I don't think so, it is possible to remove the bitterness. But you can make a curry (check some Indian recopies)  with baked eggplant. It may help.

To avoid this problem in future: 
Cut the eggplant in a salty water. Then drain it and bake it. Salt water will reduce its bitterness.

[edited based on the comment. Thanks Stephie]

Comment: The question clearly asks for dealing with bitterness *after baking*. While I agree that your method works in *raw* eggplants and hence helps *next time the asker prepares them, it does not solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score -1):

Try Chinese eggplant next time. Very little or no bitteress. They are the long and thin one usually found at Asian groceries.

Comment: While this might be good advice for next time, how does it help now?